# bug with LineBreakMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsparagraphstyle

Can you explain me why NSLineBreakByWordWrapping sometimes not working?

It's tableView

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragrahStyle setLineSpacing:4];
paragrahStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; //Char

[[cell titleLabel] setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:((Post *)posts[indexPath.section])->title attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragrahStyle, NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Condensed" size:24.0f]}]];
```

[image]

Comment: Are the words underlined 1 word or 2? If 2 it looks to be behaving as expected.

Comment: @GaryRiches, it's 1 word - "одетые"

Comment: Have you NSLogged the text to ensure there are no spaces in the data?

Comment: @GaryRiches, yes, of course. There are no spaces

Comment: where u are setting the frame of `titleLabel `

Comment: @Shan, i use storyboard. Height of each cell = height of screen ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/u93m72xjffixujz/Screenshot%202015-02-21%2013.10.21.png?dl=0 ) Second label is titleLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! ;)

I get this line in format:

> \U041f\U0438\U0440\U043e\U0436\U043d\U044b\U0435\U00a0Laduree\U00a0\U00ab\U043e\U0434\U0435\U0442\U044b\U0435\U00bb
>   \U0432\U00a0Emilio Pucci

where \U00a0 is wrong spaces (NO-BREAK SPACE), i encode this line and replace wrong spaces to normal spaces